# Grails Spring Security Custom Login Form - Where are error messages?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am new to Grails. I've configured the spring security plugin core 2.0 RC2. I am able to log in with a user stored in my database. I have configured a custom login form and when I attempt to access secure URLs without being logged in, I am redirected to my custom form. However, I have not been able to display error messages when I use a bad password or non-existent login.

I have the following snippet in my Grails.config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/user/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl  = '/user/login'
```

This seems to work. I do get to my form successfully. I am using the default LoginController that comes with the plugin.

I have tried all the following on my form:

```
<g:eachError>
    <li><g:message error="${it}"/></li>
</g:eachError>
<g:eachError>
    <li>${it}</li>
</g:eachError>
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <li> class="error">${flash.message}</li>
</g:if>
```

None shows any errors. I can see that the login controller places errors in flash:

```
def authfail() {

    String msg = ''
    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
        }
        else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
        }
        else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
        }
        else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.locked")
        }
        else {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.fail")
        }
    }

    if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
        render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
    else {
        flash.message = msg
        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}
```

, but they seem to be gone when my page is displayed. I can see the error events are raised as I have created a security event listener which logs them. Grails and Spring Security experts, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of flash.error, which will put your error message in the flash scope. Something like this:

```
if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
        flash.error = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
}
```

Then in your gsp you will need the following:

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
<div class="errors">
    <ul><li>${flash.error}</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have two questions. The SecurityEventListener is a Spring bean, not a grails component. How do you access the flash object from Spring? I have googled, but no luck finding how to do that. Also, the spring security plugin seems to be doing this already, does Spring Security do some extra redirects that make it go out of scope?

Comment: I figured out the answer to question 2. If you change the default failure url, the authfail() method in the LoginController, which adds the messages, is never called. It seems like you need to leave that setting unmodified and then it should redirect to your configured login url after authfail() is processed, like it does with the default gsp, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: I just edited the default LoginController.groovy to change authfail() to redirect to my custom form instead of the default. It seems like this is something that should come from configuration, not code, but perhaps there's a configuration I'm missing.

Comment: This should be in your grails controller, which can access the flash scope. Are you not using the Spring bean from a controller? I assume the  login controller you refer to has access to the flash scope since you are doing it with your messages already. Grails uses convention over configuration, so you are not necessarily missing any configuration.

Comment: I was trying to add the messages to flash from the SecurityEventListener, which I think has to be a Spring bean. If the plugin lets you configure a custom login form with 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl', why would it not automatically redirect to this configured form to display errors too? Who would want to use a custom form for the first attempt at login but the supplied one for subsequent attempts? I would have thought the default authfail method would use the same configuration. I did end up writing my own login controller, overriding the one in the plugin and it works.